# Python 3 Discord Bot Error: ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, bots, discord

I just wrote a simple discord bot that creates reaction polls and strawpolls and keep getting this error message after it runs for a little while.

```
    ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Here is my code

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import strawpoll
import asyncio

description = '''A bot that creates polls or strawpolls using discord'''

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='+')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('--------')
#Reaction poll
@bot.command(name="poll", pass_context=True)
async def poll(ctx):
        await bot.add_reaction(ctx.message, '')
        await bot.add_reaction(ctx.message, '')
        await bot.add_reaction(ctx.message, '')

#StrawPoll with 2 options
@bot.command(name="strawpoll2", pass_context=True)
async def poll(ctx):
    api = strawpoll.API()
    await bot.say('What would you like the title to be?')
    title = await bot.wait_for_message(author=ctx.message.author)
    await bot.say('What would you like the first choice to be?')
    choice1 = await bot.wait_for_message(author=ctx.message.author)
    await bot.say('What would you like the second choice to be?')
    choice2 = await bot.wait_for_message(author=ctx.message.author)
    p2 = strawpoll.Poll(title.content, [choice1.content, choice2.content])
    print(p2.id)                
    print(p2.url)               

    p2 = await api.submit_poll(p2)
    print(p2.id)                
    print(p2.url)

    await bot.say(p2.url)
```

I searched the error code I was getting and it didn't really give me any answers.  I also asked in the discord API discord and they said it just happens and they don't know either.

Sorry if this is formatted wrong or something it is my first time posting here.

Comment: I do get that a very few times, but it doesn't seem to have any negative effects, at most it restarts the script. Other than that, everything else usually just works fine afterwards.

Comment: @Wright it usually just ends my script.  Is there any way to make sure it just restarts it?  Because if it did that I would be fine with this happening.